# contact php sends mail but without message content

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

Okay here is the puzle; I have contact form with three part html code, script for feedback and php file for send mail.

I get mail with subject and sender name but there is no message in it. I have try to change text to html I try to send with different charset I add 
$mail->Body =$_POST['messageInput'];

nothing I need different look from yours.

HTML code:

```
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form_status"></div>
            <form id="main-contact-form" action="sendemail.php" method="post" class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="4" id="message" name"message" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 form-group">
```

is there any idea why I can not get message on e-mail body?
Thanks in advance

Comment: voted as a typo `name"message"`

Comment: *"I try to send with different charset I add $mail->Body =$_POST['messageInput'];"* - that doesn't match your input's name.

Comment: Have you tried not suppressing any errors when setting the `$message` variable? `@` does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form code

```
 <textarea class="form-control"placeholder="Message" rows="4" id="message" name"message" required></textarea>        </div>
```

You are missing the equal sign after name.

It should be
    name = "message"